# Preventing threads from writing to the same file

Tags: c, linux, networking, file-io

I'm implementing an FTP-like protocol in Linux kernel 2.4 (homework), and I was under the impression that if a file is open for writing any subsequent attempt to open it by another thread should fail, until I actually tried it and discovered it goes through.

How do I prevent this from happening?

PS: I'm using open() to open the file.

PS2: I need to be able to access existing files. I just want to prevent them being written to simultaneously.

Comment: Wait. You are doing this _in_ the Linux kernel? If you did mean a user mode process (i.e. not _in_ the kernel), are you using different threads (within same process) or different processes (i.e. are you using fork())?

Comment: I'm doing this in user mode. I guess the kernel information was indeed unimportant, but I wanted to be sure there aren't subtle bugs/differences in implementation related to the way opening files work between kernels.

Comment: What about threads (pthreads or kin) vs processes (i.e. fork). I know you have accepted an answer... still it will help future readers, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a list of open files, and then before opening a file check to see if it has already been opened by another thread. Some issues with this approach are:

- You will need to use a synchronization primitive such as a Mutex to ensure the list is thread-safe.
- Files will need to be removed from the list once your program is finished with them.

Answer (score 1):

System-level file locking is process-based, so you cannot use it. You will need to use process-level locking.  For example, by defining a mutex (lock) using pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

Use the O_CREATE and O_EXCL flags to open().  That way the call will fail if the file already exists.

Comment: This will not work for me because I need to be able to access existing files. I just want to prevent them being written to simultaneously.